# Coq, meta programming, generate fresh variable to create a Prop

Tags: metaprogramming, coq

I have my own type `Mytype`, that defines a kind of formula. I'd like to translate this formula into a Coq proposition `Prop`. To do so, I feel like I would need some kind of Meta Programming, that would let me write `forall <variable 15>, <variable 15> /\ <variable (15+1)>`.

Here is a MWE that I'd like to translate:

```
Inductive Myprop : Type :=
| MTrue
| MFalse
| MVar (_ : nat)
| MAnd (_ : Myprop) (_ : Myprop)
| MOr (_ : Myprop) (_ : Myprop)
| MForall (_ : nat) (_ : Myprop)
.

(* Exemple *)
Eval simpl in MForall 42 (MForall 42 (MOr (MVar 42) (MVar 50))).

Fixpoint translate (myprop : Myprop) : Prop :=
  match myprop with
  | MTrue => True
  | MFalse => False
  | MVar n => (* ???? Variable n ??? *)
  | MAnd a b => (translate a) /\ (translate b)
  | MOr  a b => (translate a) \/ (translate b)
  | MForall n a => forall (* ???? Variable n ??? *), (translate a)
  end.
```

Thank you!

Comment: What about taking an environment of values for your variables as an extra argument? In other words defining `translate (rho : nat -> Prop) (myprop : Myprop) : Prop`?

Comment: @gallais And you would define the variable sent by rho by `Parameter` ? First I don't see how you will deal with arbitrary big sequences, and also, I tried to write `forall (rho 0), (rho 0) /\ (rho 1).` and it returns an error `Syntax error: ':=' or ':' or [Prim.name] expected after [Prim.name] (in [constr:closed_binder]).`...

Comment: In the `MForall n a` case you would have `forall P, translate (fun m => if Nat.eqb m n then P else rho n) a`

Comment: @gallais Whooo that's great, in fact forall already create a new variable... I thought that forall P already define a P with the same variable name. Thank you ! Maybe you want to add an answer ?

Answer (score 2):

As gallais suggests, you can augment your `translate` function with a context lookup function:

```
Fixpoint translate (lookup : nat -> Prop) (myprop : Myprop) : Prop :=
  match myprop with
  | MTrue => True
  | MFalse => False
  | MVar n => lookup n
  | MAnd a b => (translate lookup a) /\ (translate lookup b)
  | MOr  a b => (translate lookup a) \/ (translate lookup b)
  | MForall n a => forall p : Prop,
      translate (fun n' => if Nat.eqb n' n then p else lookup n') a
  end.

Eval compute in translate _ (MForall 42 (MForall 42 (MOr (MVar 42) (MVar 50)))).
(* Prop -> forall p0 : Prop, p0 \/ ?lookup 50 *)
```

Another approach is to use HOAS (Higher-Order Abstract Syntax), and let your bindings be Gallina bindings:

```
Inductive Myprop : Type :=
| MTrue
| MFalse
| MVar (_ : Prop)
| MAnd (_ : Myprop) (_ : Myprop)
| MOr (_ : Myprop) (_ : Myprop)
| MForall (_ : Prop -> Myprop)
.

(* Exemple *)
Eval simpl in MForall (fun p42 => MForall (fun p42 => MOr (MVar p42) (MVar ?[p50]))).
(* ?[p50] denotes a fresh evar named "p50" *)

Fixpoint translate (myprop : Myprop) : Prop :=
  match myprop with
  | MTrue => True
  | MFalse => False
  | MVar P => P
  | MAnd a b => (translate a) /\ (translate b)
  | MOr  a b => (translate a) \/ (translate b)
  | MForall P => forall p : Prop, translate (P p)
  end.

Eval simpl in translate (MForall (fun p42 => MForall (fun p42 => MOr (MVar p42) (MVar ?[p50])))).
(* forall p p0 : Prop, p0 \/ ?p50@{p43:=p; p42:=p0} *)
```